# Facebook Application Safari issue [redirecting to index.php]

Tags: php, facebook, safari, facebook-apps

ı have facebook application. **it works on ffox, chrome, maxthon etc.**

my problem is: ı have a admin panel link in my application when ı click the link in safari its not following the link. redirecting to index.php again.

ı have a link to this page **apps.facebook.com/myapp/admin.php** but safari redirect me to **apps.facebook.com/myapp/**

works on other browsers.

Comment: Does safari have any dev tools where you can watch the redirects happen? Might shed some light on your situation.

Comment: ı read something about cross domain cookies may it cause the problem.

ı dont use safari so ı dont know dev tools